# Criar um contagem com JS puro

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando fazer um código que quando a página carregar ele começar a contar e terminar no número que quero,Ex: 0 a 60

*Eu sei como parar o loop,só não consegui fazer-lo iniciar a contagem*

### Tentei usando setTimeout()

```
function carregar (){

var c = 0;

setTimeout (function (){

document.getElementById("htmlp").innerHTML = c + "%";

c = c + 1;

}, 1000);
}
```

tentei a mesma coisa com setInterval () ja que é um loop mas não deu em nada tbm

Comment: E onde está o número `60` que vc quer finalizar a contagem?

Comment: Eu ia explicar ali mais acabei esquecendo,eu ja sei como parar a contagem,só não sei como inicia-la. A cada 1 segundo adicionar +1 e ir a 2 tlgd? Essa eu não consegui fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É mais fácil usar `setInterval`, porque é um temporizador contínuo, que você pode pará-lo com `clearInterval()`. Mas é preciso atribui-lo à uma variável. Se tiver dentro de uma função, basta chamar a função.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei o tempo até 10 segundos para ilustrar:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // aguarda o DOM ser carregado
   var c = 0;
   var fim = 10;
   function carregar (){
     var contagem = setInterval(function(){
         if(c > fim){
            clearInterval(contagem);
         }else{
            document.getElementById("htmlp").innerHTML = c + "%";
            c = c + 1;
         }
      }, 1000);
   }
   carregar(); // inicia a função
});
```

```html
<div id="htmlp"></div>
```